# How may i group this data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have a table called

```
 CountryVisits

Visitor      Date
  4        20/12/12 14:27:7 
  5        20/12/12 15:45:11 
  6        20/12/12 16:36:51 
  12       21/12/12 11:17:2 
  145      21/12/12 12:37:57 
  445      21/12/12 13:35:15 
  435      21/12/12 14:34:35
```

I want to have a count of all visitors per Date not time :

So i expect :

```
VisitorCnt      Date
  3           20/12/12   
  4           21/12/12
```

I tried :

```
SELECT  COUNT(DATE(Date)), DATE(Date) from CountryVisits GROUP BY Date ;
```

But i don't have the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `GROUP BY Date` it's grouping by the `Date` column in the table, which includes times. If you want to group by just the day, you need to assign an alias and group by that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(Date) AS VisitedOn
FROM CountryVisits
GROUP BY VisitedOn
```